# jobs -l command needs to be run twice to update?

Tags: ksh, jobs

I'm trying to create a while loop that waits for a copy job to complete. To get the status of the running jobs, I'm using:
 jobs -l | grep -c "Running"

I have simplified it to the code below. When the job completes, it will print out "successfully executed command". What i see is that the job completes, but the while loop always does an extra loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
execCmd()
{
    $*
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        exit
    else
        echo  "successfully executed command: \"$*\""
    fi
}

execCmd "sleep 10"& 

NPROC=`jobs -l | grep -c "Running"`

while [[ $NPROC != "0" ]]; do
   echo "$NPROC copy script is still working..."
   sleep 2
   NPROC=`jobs -l | grep -c "Running"`
   echo $NPROC
done
```

The only way I have found to solve this is to run the  `jobs -l` command twice, e.g:

```
jobs -l
NPROC=`jobs -l | grep -c "Running"`
```

Why does jobs -l not get updated straight away when my execCmd function finishes?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you detaching a sleep command that does nothing?  If you want to set an alarm for yourself, that ain't the way to do it.  (You would sleep and then kill -14 $$, but I digress.)

While loops don't loop an extra time; they only loop while the condition is true.  Thus, the condition that you feel should be false is, in fact, true.

Because it is detached, the sleep may not have started before the first while test executes. You can save yourself heartache by sleeping for one second before the while test.

Comment: I realise it looks silly here, but I have massively simplified the script. Imagine the sleep command is something that is a real process. The reason I detach it is because the end goal is to run a few of these commands simultaneously.

Comment: I'm not delaying for ten seconds and then assuming it has worked. The whole point is it will stay in the while loop until all the jobs have finished, even if they take longer than expected. If you actually run the above code, you will see that the command finishes (when it prints out "successfully executed command:", and then the while loop will print out one extra "copy script is still working...".